# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL with some warnings

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I downloaded an open-source sql injection application. When I tried to run it gives me error "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" and some warnings as well. I am sharing my code and some images.

HTML:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO- 8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Login Page</title>

   <form action="userCheck">

   <div>

   <input type="text" name="user" value=""/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </div>


   </form>
   </head>
   <body>

    </body>
   </html>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name></display-name>


      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>userCheck</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>RKINJ.userCheck</servlet-class>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>userCheck</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/userCheck</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Java:

```
package RKINJ;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class userCheck extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("'text/html;charset=UTF-8'");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            String user = request.getParameter("name");
            Connection conn = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logindb";
           // String dbName = "logindb";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "test1234";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                String query = "SELECT * FROM  userdetail where id='' + user + ''";
               // out.println("Query : " + query);
            //    System.out.printf(query);
                ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(query);

            //    out.println("Results");
                while (res.next()) {
                    String s = res.getString("name");
                    out.println("\t\t" + s);
                }
                conn.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }

}}
```

These are few warnings I got when run the program

```
Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.6. There are no  JREs    installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this  environment. 

Classpath entry C:/Java-Programs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin-folder.jar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result. 

Classpath entry C:/Java-Programs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.

Invalid location of tag (form). login.jsp   /RKINJ/WebContent   line 9  JSP Problem.

The serializable class userCheck does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long
```

Comment: And to fix this `The serializable class userCheck does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long` warning you need to add for example this: `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` line to your userCheck Class. 

And it is good practice to write Class names  with uppercase first letter `UserCheck`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override doPost method that in the servlet.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
```

Comment: protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
           throws ServletException, java.io.IOException.
Use this signature and verify you don't call super

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the action method

```
<form action"something" Method="POST / Get">
```

And you need also to override doPost method that in the servlet.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
```

I wish i was helpfull